# How do I keep the renderBlocks() function from going into an infinite loop?

Tags: lua, infinite-loop

```
-- This is Minecraft, but 2D, and in Lua.

-- **************************************
-- ID 0: Air
-- ID 1: Stone
-- ID 2 Logs
-- ID 3: Leaves
-- ID 4: Planks
-- ID 5: Crafting Table
-- ID 6: Furnance
-- ID 7: Player position detector block
-- **************************************

blockTable = { -- Stores all the blocks
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6}
}
tableRow = 1 -- Y value for block render pointer
tableColumn = 1 -- X value for block render pointer
runOnce = true -- Run a loop once
tickNum = 0 -- Number of ticks since startup
function renderBlock(X, Y, K) -- Render a block
    if K == 1 then -- if blockID == 1, draw a grey square
        screen.setColor(100,100,100)
        print(X, Y)
        screen.drawRectF(X, Y, 8, 8)
    end
    if K == 6 then -- If the blockID == draw a grey square
        screen.setColor(100,100,100)
        screen.drawRectF(X, Y, 8, 8)
    end
end

function renderBlocks() -- Render all the blocks (Scans though the blockTable in a raster pattern)
        while runOnce == true -- Run this code once
    do
    while #blockTable >= tableRow
    do
        while #blockTable[tableRow] >= tableColumn
        do
            print("TC " .. tableColumn)
            tableColumn = tableColumn + 1
            
            blockID = blockTable[tableRow][tableColumn]
            renderBlock(tableRow, tableColumn, blockID)
            if tableColumn > #blockTable[tableRow] then tableColumn = 1 end
        end
        runOnce = false
    end
        print("TR " .. tableRow)
        tableRow = tableRow + 1
    end
end

function onTick()
    print("Tick! Tick count: " .. tickNum) -- Print the current tick, as well as say that there has been a tick
    tickNum = tickNum + 1
end

function onDraw()
    while runOnce == true -- Run this code once
    do
    renderBlocks()
    runOnce = false
    end
end
```

Here's my code in the IDE for the framework: [Link](https://lua.flaffipony.rocks/?id=SBn-aAGLW6)

I have no clue why this is happening, I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Add your code in your post in here. It is not intended to have to look on other sites to help you.

Comment: In general terms to avoid an infinite loop you need to have a condition to end and you need to check for it on each start or end of the loop (while or repeat) or before you recall the recursive function.

Comment: When would `tableRow` ever change to make `#blockTable >= tableRow` false?

Comment: It might be that you have simply inverted row and column for the checks, and that makes it that your code runs in an infinite loop. Since there are more elements in the inner tables than innerTables in the outsideTable. So perhaps #blockTable[tableRow] >= tableColumn or #blockTable[tableRow] >= tableColumn is always true. Have not checked it. Either way, I would recommend you my awnser below, since it is far more readable (shorter!) and works.

Answer (score 1):

When doing loops over tables it is far better to use for loops than while or repeat loops, that are far more difficult to understand and bugfix.

Use `for index,value in ipairs(yourtable) do` if you want to get the indices (number in the table) and the values associated or `for key,value in pairs(yourtable) do` if you want to get the keys (generally strings that is used as key for a value: `yourTable["key"] = 0`) and the values associated with it.

```
for row,innerTable in ipairs(blockTable) do
        
    for col,value in ipairs(innerTable) do
            
        print("TC " .. col)
            
        blockID = value
        renderBlock(row, col, blockID)
            
    end
        
end
```

The last should do it inside your renderBlocks function. But that:

```
while runOnce == true do

    -- Doing something
    runOnce = false

end
```

Is not very nice stuff. If it shall only be called once, do not put it into a loop!

Also it would help to have a little better code identation to understand what is happening faster. And add some Space between blocks of code that handle different concerns.

Edit: So your function could look like this:

```
function renderBlocks()
    if runOnce then
        runOnce = false
        for row,innerTable in ipairs(blockTable) do
            for col,value in ipairs(innerTable) do
                blockID = value
                renderBlock(row, col, blockID)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The main onDraw() function is called every tick outside of the Lua script, it would run more than once if I didn't do that. Also, I'm not that good with the indentation, I never really learned that stuff..

Comment: just use if runOnce then --[[ here the for loops ]] end. This will make it be done only once too if you set runOnce to false inside the if statement. Also when checking a condition you don't need to compare it with true if the value in question is either true or false, that is why I do not the comparison.

Comment: for indentation in lua the short idea is, when you use a keyword that starts a block indent by one tab or 4 spaces after and remove it again with the end keyword. This makes your different blocks of code better readable, and it is easier to see imediately what is a block and where it ends.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example how the function could look now. And I saw another potential problem. You are using runOnce for the renderBlocks function and for the onDraw function. But which either is called first would set runOnce to false and the other not beeing called. If both need to be called once, it would probably be good to use separate variables like renderBlockHasNotRun and onDrawHasNotRun...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues in your `renderBlocks()` function

```lua
function renderBlocks()
  while runOnce == true do
    while #blockTable >= tableRow do
      while #blockTable[tableRow] >= tableColumn do
        print("TC " .. tableColumn)
        tableColumn = tableColumn + 1

        blockID = blockTable[tableRow][tableColumn]
        renderBlock(tableRow, tableColumn, blockID)
        if tableColumn > #blockTable[tableRow] then 
          tableColumn = 1 
        end
      end
      runOnce = false
    end
    print("TR " .. tableRow)
    tableRow = tableRow + 1
  end
end
```

First we can look at the inner most loop. Here we have a problem with the contrition used to evaluate the loop and how it is incremented.

```lua
while #blockTable[tableRow] >= tableColumn do
  print("TC " .. tableColumn)
  tableColumn = tableColumn + 1 -- incremented here

  blockID = blockTable[tableRow][tableColumn]
  renderBlock(tableRow, tableColumn, blockID)
  if tableColumn > #blockTable[tableRow] then 
    tableColumn = 1 -- reset here
  end
end
```

in the loop body you do `tableColumn = tableColumn + 1` and later in the same body you do `if tableColumn > #blockTable[tableRow] then tableColumn = 1 end` so this is a problem when `tableColumn` is increased to a value that would end the loop we reset it to `1` preventing the loop from ever ending.

Now lets look at the next loop up. Here we never increment `tableRow` it is incremented just after the end of this loop so it is not possible for the loop to end.

```lua
while #blockTable >= tableRow do
    while #blockTable[tableRow] >= tableColumn do
        ...
    end
    runOnce = false
end
```

I believe you intended

```lua
print("TR " .. tableRow)
tableRow = tableRow + 1
```

to occur within this loop not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few block definitions here.  Don't think that's what's sending it into an infinite loop, but you might not see results, otherwise.

```
function renderBlock(X, Y, blockID)  --  Render a block
  if blockID == 0 then  --  Air
    --  screen.setColor(10, 20, 220, 0) -- is there an alpha channel?
    screen.setColor(10, 20, 220)

  elseif blockID == 1 then  --  Stone
    screen.setColor(100, 100, 100)

  elseif blockID == 2 then  --  Logs
    screen.setColor(200, 50, 50)

  elseif blockID == 3 then  --  Leaves
    screen.setColor(20, 220, 40)

  elseif blockID == 4 then  --  Planks
    screen.setColor(180, 30, 10)

  elseif blockID == 5 then  --  Craft Table
    screen.setColor(180, 30, 10)

  elseif blockID == 6 then  --  Furnace
    screen.setColor(100, 100, 100)

  elseif blockID == 7 then  --  Player detect
    screen.setColor(220, 30, 30)
  end

  print(X, Y)
  screen.drawRectF(X, Y, 8, 8)
end
```

It's easy to use `for` loops.  set initial condition, then the final, completed condition, and let it run the course.

```
function renderBlocks() -- Render all blocks (Scans though blockTable in a raster pattern)
  for row = 1,  #blockTable do
    for col = 1, #blockTable[row] do
      print("TC " ..col)
      local blockID = blockTable[row][col]
      renderBlock(row, col, blockID)
    end
    print("TR " ..row)
  end
end
```

You likely don't need that `runOnce`.  If you find you do for something else, go ahead, but it shouldn't be needed with a nested for loop.

```
function onDraw()
  renderBlocks()
end
```

Comment: might need to flip `blockTable[col][row]` for your data block.  you get the idea tho